# Why is a float an "unexpected type"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm starting out with OpenGL. I installed the GLEW and GLFW libraries in Visual Studio C++ Community (running on Windows 10). Then I followed a tutorial and was able to draw a rectangle on a window. I continued to follow the tutorial until I got to a part where you would add:

```
glViewport(0.0f, 0.0f, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Even after I added that, the quad was still being drawn. In the video, the tutor's rectangle was too small for the window, but on my machine everything went fine and the rectangle was the same size as it was before adding those lines (even though my array used decimals).
I started looking for something that would "invalidate" those lines. After a while I ignored them.

But after I deleted them and tried to create another quad, the compiler said that a float was an "unexpected type" on the function glVertexPointer.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD6fk.png)

How can I solve this problem?
Here is the source code:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480


int main(void) {

GLFWwindow *window;


if (!glfwInit()) {
    return -1;
};


window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "OGL", NULL, NULL);

if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
};

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

float vertices[] = {

    -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.0

};

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, float, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

}

glfwTerminate();

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the line it's complaining about is:

```
glVertexPointer(3, float, 0, vertices);
```

I think what you meant was:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
```

The difference here is that `float` is a type, and `GL_FLOAT` is a value.  You can't pass a type as a parameter to a function.  That second parameter is required to be of type `GLenum`.

More information here: [glVertexPointer](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)

Comment: Holy crap! It's bitmap! I recommend making a new question when you have a new question, @slashblock

Comment: The type of the array still has to be float not GL_FLOAT. You have to learn where you use types and where you have to use GLenums.

Comment: I am profoundly confused. Why did the exact same code work before? Do I need to reinstall Visual Studio? Iz my compudar broken?

Comment: Look, just take the code exactly as you had posted it, but ONLY make the change that I mentioned on the one line.  Your mistake was turning _other_ usages of `float` into `GL_FLOAT`, but I never said you should do that.

Comment: I made a new project and i put GL_FLOAT as the parameter for GLenum in glVertexPointer and float as an identifier for the array. Now it works.

Comment: That is correct.  Passing `GL_FLOAT` to `glVertexPointer` is telling that function that the `void*` in the 4th parameter is actually a `float*`.

Comment: Is it casting float to GL_FLOAT?

Comment: No, it's not.  `GL_FLOAT` is not a type.  It's one possible value of the `GLenum` enumeration.  Imagine that inside `glVertexPointer` there is a `switch` statement saying _"what type of data did they give me?"_.  We passed `GL_FLOAT`, so it knows to interpret `vertices` as a `float` array.  If you are still confused, I suggest you read up about the difference between _types_ and _values_.

Answer (score 2):

`float` is a reserved word indicating a type, and isn't valid for passing as a parameter. You need `GL_FLOAT` instead. See https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml